# Complex Zend Query from same user table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a rather unique set of conditions and orders in which I need to retrieve data from a "sellers" table for an application I'm building in Zend framework.

The client is basically requesting an application where the directory page lists sellers in a very particular order, which is:

1. Sellers who have been approved in the last 7 days (then order by #4 below)
2. Then, selllers who have paid for upgraded features on the site, and are more the 7 days old (then order by #4 below)
3. Then, Sellers who are more than 7 days old and are more than 7 days old (then order by #4 below)
4. For all of the above, secondary order by would be their launch date, then alpha by business name

I'm trying to figure out the most effective way to write an action helper that will return the data in the correct sequence above, knowing that some of my views only need 1,2 (and 4), whereas other views within the application will need all 4.

Right now, I've been writing two or three separate queries, and passing them to 2 or 3 `partialloop`'s inside the view, but I strive for properly written code, and would like to either combine my 3 queries into one object I can pass to one partial loop, or.... write one query.  How can this be done?

Here's my helper at the moment:

```
class Plugin_Controller_Action_Helper_ListSellers extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract
{

//put your code here
public function direct($regulars = false, $filter = false)
{
    $dateMod = $this->dateMod = new DateTime();
    $dateMod->modify('-7 days');
    $formattedDate = $dateMod->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    // get sellers initialized in last 7 days
    $sellerTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_Seller();



        // get sellers initialized in last 7 days
        $select = $sellerTable->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
        $select->from(array('b' => 'seller'),array('sellerID', 'businessName','sellerPicture'));
        // select firstName, lastName, picture from user table, and businessName and sellerID from seller table.  All records from seller table
        $select->join(array('u' => 'user'), 's.userID = u.userID', array('firstName', 'lastName'));
        $select->order('s.launchDate DESC','s.businessName ASC');
        $select->where('s.active = 1 AND s.contentApproval = 1 AND s.paymentApproval = 1');
        $select->where('s.launchDate > ?', $formattedDate);
        if($filter){ $select->where('s.categoryID = ?', $filter);}
        $newSellers = $sellerTable->fetchAll($select);



        $query = $sellerTable->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
        $query->from(array('b' => 'seller'),array('sellerID', 'businessName','sellerPicture'));
        // select firstName, lastName, picture from user table, and businessName and sellerID from seller table.  All records from seller table
        $query->join(array('u' => 'user'), 's.userID = u.userID', array('firstName', 'lastName'));
        $query->order('s.launchDate DESC','s.businessName ASC');

        $query->where('s.active = 1 AND s.contentApproval = 1 AND s.paymentApproval = 1 AND s.featured = 1');
        $query->where('s.launchDate < ?', $formattedDate);
        if($filter){ $select->where('s.categoryID = ?', $filter);}
        $featuredSellers = $sellerTable->fetchAll($query);


    if($regulars){
        $where = $sellerTable->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
        $where->from(array('b' => 'seller'),array('sellerID', 'businessName','sellerPicture'));
        // select firstName, lastName, picture from user table, and businessName and sellerID from seller table.  All records from seller table
        $where->join(array('u' => 'user'), 's.userID = u.userID', array('firstName', 'lastName'));
        $where->order('s.launchDate DESC','s.businessName ASC');

        $where->where('s.active = 1 AND s.contentApproval = 1 AND s.paymentApproval = 1 AND s.featured IS NULL');
        $where->where('s.launchDate < ?', $formattedDate);
        $regularSellers = $sellerTable->fetchAll($where);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any limits being applied to your queries.  So does that mean you really want to select *all* matching records?  For scalability reasons I'd guess that the answer should be no, there will be limits applied.  In this case, you may just have to do 3 different queries.

But if there are no limits to be applied, then you could do a single simple query that selects all sellers, unfiltered and unsorted, and do your sorting and filtering in view helpers or just in your views.

Regardless, I recommend not putting database queries inside your controller layer, assuming you want to use the [Model-View-Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which Zend is built for.  Controllers should be thin.  Your models should handle all database queries and just spit out the results into your controllers.  I use the [Data Mapper pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) extensively.  Something like:

```
$mapper = new Application_Model_SellerMapper();

$newSellers = $mapper->fetchNewSellers();
$featuredSellers = $mapper->fetchFeaturedSellers();
$regularSellers = $mapper->fetchRegularSellers();
```

Each of your `fetchX()` methods would return an array of `Application_Model_Seller` instances, rather than `Zend_Db_Table_Row` instances.

This way you maintain [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) better, for more maintainable code.  Even if you're the only developer on the project over the long-term, 6 months from now you won't remember what you wrote and why.  And if someone else comes on the project, clarity becomes *really* important.

Comment: Yes, all results would be selected in the query, as I plan to plug in `Zend_Paginator`.  It took me a minute but I see what you mean by moving the queries out of the helper and into the models.  Can those results still be passed to the view helper `partialloop`?

Comment: Yes, you can pass them to `partialloop`.  It accepts any array, or even an object if it has public properties.  But Zend_Paginator requires a `Zend_Db_Select` statement as I recall.  Using that paginator kind of goes against MVC to do it this way, but every OOP rule has an exception somewhere.

Comment: This app would potentially have sellers in the 1,000's.  As long as you've got me in the mood to juggle this much code around, any suggestions on alternatives to `Zend_Paginator`?  Users still need to be able to next/prev through lists of providers in addition to searching. Limit parameters in the fetchers?

Comment: I typically roll my own pagination functionality.  It's not hard.  I use a custom view helper I wrote, which renders the links for the pager.  Important variables are `$currentPage` and `$totalPages`.  You'll need to convert these to/from a database offset too.

Comment: Yeah, the mapper methods for fetching sellers would need to accept two parameters: `$count` and `$offset`, which are converted from `$itemsPerPage` and `$pageNum` in your views.  It might be easier not to worry about the latter set, and just use `$count` and `$offset` in your view too.

Comment: So as I've been looking to move a bunch of code out of the controller layer and into the data layer, I kind of expected there to be an abstract in ZF (1.11) for the Data Mapper pattern... but finding there isn't. Sounds like you've got experience here, so what was your approach? Create your own abstract? use the table models? Convert Row instances into Mapper instances?

Comment: I make my own data mapper abstract classes.  I've seen requests for abstract models shipped with ZF, but the devs believe this is totally up to the developer, so they don't bother including one.  It's easy though.  Just make a plain old PHP class, mark it Abstract, and include whatever standard `Zend_Db` stuff your other mappers will need.

Comment: Got it... thanks a bunch.  Any more and I'd owe you a tuition check. :)

Comment: Don't give up Zend_Paginator yet, it does take multiple different adapters is fairly easy to extend to incorporate your [domain models](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/exploring-zend-paginator/), also if you need a bit of help getting started with mappers I found [Survive the Deepend](http://survivethedeepend.com/) and [Alejandro Gervasio's articles at PHPMaster](http://phpmaster.com/author/agervasio/) helpful.